# Why my navbar item isn't sticking to the bottom of the screen?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I created a footer component with the following CSS :

```
.footer {
    background-color: rgb(10, 4, 22);
    bottom: 0 !important;
    padding-top: 10px !important;
    padding-bottom: 8px !important;
}
```

Now in my `App.js` I add the `footer` component and for all of my pages it's working fine except the page `claim` :

```
        <Router>
            <Pre load={load}/>
            <div className="App" id={load ? "no-scroll" : "scroll"}>
                <Navigation/>
                <ScrollToTop/>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/" element={<Home/>}/>
                    <Route path="/about" element={<About/>}/>
                    <Route path="/hunt" element={<Hunt/>}/>
                    <Route path="/roadmap" element={<Roadmap/>}/>
                    <Route path="/whitepaper" element={<Whitepaper/>}/>
                    <Route path="/genZero" element={<GenZero/>}/>
                    <Route path="/claim" element={<Claim/>}/>
                </Routes>
                <Footer/>
            </div>
        </Router>
```

On the `claim` page, the footer isn't at the bottom of the screen :
[image]

But on every other page it's working fine. This is my `claim` component :

```
import React from "react";
import {Container} from "react-bootstrap";
import Claimable from "./Claimable";

function Claim() {
    return (
        <Container fluid className="claim-section">
            <Container>
                <h1 className="team-heading">
                  TODO
                </h1>
                <Claimable/>
            </Container>
        </Container>
    );
}

export default Claim;
```

it's the same structure as `about` component, where the footer is at the bottom of the screen. So how can I make it stick to the bottom of the screen for every component ?

Comment: Maybe you have ```height``` property on ```claim``` page?

Comment: I'm not sure why are you using a `bottom: 0` if this prop doesn't work with default position of the element. Try to use inspector tool to figure out what's preventing from pushing it to the bottom. Usually you use something like `height: 100%` attached to the `html` and `body` tags

Comment: Thank you for both your input now it's working !

Answer (score 0):

You need to add position fixed to the footer

```
.footer { 
    position: fixed;
    background-color: rgb(10, 4, 22);
    bottom: 0 !important;
    padding-top: 10px !important;
    padding-bottom: 8px !important;
}
```

You can try position fixed or absolute whichever works.
And my suggestion to please remove `!important` from the CSS code, that might cause problems manipulating the properties on later end